# How to set TTL (expiry) on keys in Consul KV store

Tags: distributed, consul

I am essentially using Consul alongside a health checking service to store health check error messages from some number of remote hosts (key: hostname => value: message). However, I want the key-value pair to be deleted if it hasn't been updated in over 24 hours, for example, if the remote host is removed entirely from health check rotation.

According to the [Consul API documentation](https://www.consul.io/api/session.html), you can set a TTL on a `session` when it is created. It seems you can then bind this `session` to a particular key with the `acquire` parameter when you [Create/Update a key](https://www.consul.io/api/kv.html#create-update-key), and when the session expires, it will also delete the key. The caveat is that `acquire` also locks the key, which to me implies the value cannot be set by anyone else until it is later updated with the `release` parameter, but this removes the session->key association (ultimately removing the TTL on the key).

It isn't clear how to implement implement a simple TTL for keys in a Consul key-value store. It seems something like this could work, but I'm not sure how to keep the sessions associated with the keys:

1. Create Session with `TTL=86400s` and get the `sessionID`
2. Create Key-Value pair with `acquire=sessionID`
3. ??? `release=sessionID` ???
4. Every time the key-value pair is updated, refresh the session TTL

And repeat the above for every new key-value pair inserted.

Can someone please elaborate on how to use sessions to remove expired key-value pairs from Consul?

Comment: Consul locks are only advisory. Acquiring a lock on a key does not prevent another node from modifying the value associated with the key... it just prevents other nodes from acquiring a lock on that key. (At least that's the behavior in version 1.2.3.)

Answer (score 3):

While creating a session, you can specify the behaviour to be of `delete` type and TTL can be set to 24hrs (check https://www.consul.io/api/session.html#ttl). So, if the session is not renewed within the time limit specified, then the key is automatically deleted (https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/sessions.html).